# Limit the width of the text in an input not working on phones

Tags: html, jquery

I got a piece of code supposed to limit the width of the text inserted by the user in an input field. The idea is that the username can't be longer than the width of 9's W WWWWWWWWWW.

I managed (using code parts from here) to do this:

```
$('html').keyup(function(e){if(e.keyCode == 8)checkUserWidth();}) 
function Measure(font) {
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.ctx.font = font;

    // method to call to measure width in pixels
    this.getWidth = function(txt) {
      return this.ctx.measureText(txt).width
    };
  }

  // set up a global instance
  var m = new Measure("12pt sans-serif");

  // get funky
  document.querySelector("#usuario").onkeyup = function() {
    var w = Math.ceil(m.getWidth(this.value)); // round up in case of float
    $("#measure").val(w);
  };
      
  function checkUserWidth() {
      setTimeout(function() {
         var uwidth = $('#measure').val();
         if (uwidth > 136) {
              $(".userinput").css("border","2px solid red");
              $(".longError").css("display","block");
              $(".sendform").css("opacity","0.5");
              $(".sendform").attr("disabled","disabled");
          } else if (uwidth == 152) {
              $(".userinput").css("border","2px solid green");
              $(".longError").css("display","none");
              $(".sendform").css("opacity","1");
              $(".sendform").attr("disabled",false);
          } else if (uwidth == 0) {
              $(".userinput").css("border","thin solid #a5a5a5");
              $(".longError").css("display","none");
          } else {
              $(".userinput").css("border","2px solid green");
              $(".longError").css("display","none");
              $(".sendform").css("opacity","1");
              $(".sendform").attr("disabled",false);
          }
        }, 300);
  }

<input type="text" class="userinput" id="usuario" name="usuario" maxlength="21" onKeyPress="checkUserWidth()" required/>
          <span class="longError" style="display:none;color:red;"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> El nombre de usuario es demasiado largo.</span>
          <span class="usedError" style="display:none;color:red;"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> El nombre de usuario ya esta en uso.</span>
          <input type="hidden" id="measure" value="0"/>
```

The code works fine in PC as the event is triggered on keyup. The problem comes when done with mobile, as the event is not triggered anymore.

is there a way to update this so it works in phones aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually implement it in a much simpler way, just by using the `keypress` event, and performing width checks each time a key is pressed.

First, you need to remove the `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` events from your input element, and the second input element as well:

```
<input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" required/>
```

and then, you need to add a listener to your input element, for each time a key is pressed:

```
  // set up a global instance
  var m = new Measure("12pt sans-serif");
  var w = 0;

  $("#usuario").on('keyup', function(e){
    w = Math.ceil(m.getWidth(this.value)); // round up in case of float
    console.log(w);
  });
  
  $('#usuario').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(w > 121){
       if(e.keyCode != 8){
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log("no puede seguir escribiendo"+w);
          console.log(w);
       }
    }
    else {
       console.log("puede seguir escribiendo"+w);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I've updated the question as I managed to sort out the backspace issue. I have a new issue, as it doesn't work on phones now because the event is triggered with keyup... do you know how to update the code so it works in phones?

Comment: Instead of "keypress" you could try using "keyup touchend".

Comment: @Charlie I have updated my answer, you can test it and see if it's ok.

Comment: @VasilisG. I've managed to sort it out with on.('keyup touchend', function(e).... It now works on phones aswell. Thanks!